# Tkinter: Embedding a populated Frame in a Canvas window

Tags: tkinter, scrollbar, python-3.7, tkinter-canvas

Since the tkinter Frame widget does not support scrolling, my beginner self decided to explore the possibility of using a canvas to harbour a previously populated frame. In the code I reproduce below I have two problems I cannot deal with: why the left topmost widget takes such a large space; why the app takes all available screen space, even shortening the widgets, thus not showing the scroll slider. All suggestions most welcome.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
class Calc_Table(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, cols, rows):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=root)
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        hscrollbar = Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hscrollbar.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = EW)
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = NS)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, xscrollcommand = hscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand =                     vscrollbar.set,bg='yellow')
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)
        self.canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        hscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        vscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)
        self.initial_table = self.create_table(self.cols,self.rows)
        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = self.initial_table,
                                                  width=400, height=200, anchor=NW)
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))

    def create_table(self, cols, rows):             # build initial table ---->
        self.cols, self.rows = cols, rows
        for c in range(self.cols):         
            for r in range(self.rows):
                if c == 0 and r == 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self, width=6, height=1, bg="white",
                                text="? ? ?", relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
                elif c == 0 and r != 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self, width=6, height=1, bg="white", 
                                text=f"R{r}",relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
                elif c != 0 and r == 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self, width=6, height=1, bg="white",
                                text=f"C{c}",relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
                else:
                    self.txt =Text(self, width=6, height=1, bg="white",
                               relief=SUNKEN)
                    self.txt.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=NSEW)
        for c in range(self.cols):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
                for r in range(self.rows):
                    self.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cols = int(input("How many columns? "))
    assert isinstance(int(cols), int), "integers only, please"
    rows = int(input("How many rows? "))
    assert isinstance(int(rows), int), "integers only, please"
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("+10+10")
    root.title("Master Table")
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_table = Calc_Table(root, cols, rows)
    my_table.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW)
    my_table.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_table.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Below please find the code, amended, but with the frame and widgets inside the canvas still unable to expand:

```
from tkinter import *
class Calc_Table(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, cols, rows):
        Frame.__init__(self, master=root)
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        hscrollbar = Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL)
        hscrollbar.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = EW)
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL)
        vscrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = NS)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, xscrollcommand = hscrollbar.set,      yscrollcommand = vscrollbar.set, bg='yellow')
        self.canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = NSEW)
        self.canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        hscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.xview)
        vscrollbar.config(command = self.canvas.yview)

        self.table_frame = self.create_table(self.cols,self.rows)
        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window = self.table_frame, anchor=NW)
        self.canvas.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion = self.canvas.bbox('all'))
        print(self.canvas.find_all())          #check canvas slaves
        print(len(self.table_frame.grid_slaves()))   #check table_frame slaves

    def create_table(self, cols, rows):     # build initial table ---->
        self.table_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
        self.table_frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = NSEW)
        self.cols, self.rows = cols, rows
        for c in range(self.cols):
            for r in range(self.rows):
                if c == 0 and r == 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white",text="? ? ?", relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1,sticky=NSEW)
                elif c == 0 and r != 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white", text=f"R{r}",relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1,sticky=NSEW)
                elif c != 0 and r == 0:
                    self.lbl = Label(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white",text=f"C{c}",relief=RAISED)
                    self.lbl.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1,sticky=NSEW)
                else:
                    self.txt =Text(self.table_frame, width=6, height=1, bg="white", relief=SUNKEN)
                    self.txt.grid(column=c, row=r, padx=1, pady=1,sticky=NSEW)
        self.table_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.table_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        for c in range(self.cols):
              self.table_frame.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
            for r in range(self.rows):
              self.table_frame.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)  # end table
        return self.table_frame

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cols = int(input("How many columns? "))
    assert isinstance(int(cols), int), "integers only, please"
    rows = int(input("How many rows? "))
    assert isinstance(int(rows), int), "integers only, please"
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("+10+10")
    root.title("Master Table")
    root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_table = Calc_Table(root, cols, rows)
    my_table.configure(bg = "green")
    my_table.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW)
    my_table.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    my_table.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Some of the indentation is your code is correct. What level is `for r in range(self.rows)` supposed to be at?

Answer (score 0):

> why the left topmost widget takes such a large space

The main reason is because the canvas is in row 0, column zero of `self`, and the default size of a canvas is around 200 pixels. If you change the height of the canvas, you will see that the size of the row changes by the same amount.

The other problem is that all of the widgets you're creating in `create_table` are being given `self` as the master. If you are trying to create a scrollable table, those need to be children of a frame that is inside the canvas.

> why the app takes all available screen space, even shortening the widgets, thus not showing the scroll slider.

For the same reasons as before - `create_table` is putting widgets in the root window, and putting them in the same row and column as the scrollbar.

---

The fundamental thing you're doing wrong is that you aren't creating a frame inside the canvas. You need to create a frame in `create_table`, put all other widgets in `create_table` inside this frame, and then make sure that `create_table` returns this frame.

```
def create_table(self, cols, rows):
    table_frame = Frame(self.canvas)
    ...
            self.lbl = Label(table_frame, ...)
    ...
    return table_frame
```

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested; unsurprisingly, it did work. Unfortunately, in order to gain scrolling one loses expansion: the frame inside the canvas and its children do not expand, even though I sprayed grid_columnconfigure and grid_rowconfigure where applicable. Thks for your support.

Comment: @user2328909: The frame should expand or contract to fit its contents unless you're doing something to prevent that. You're explicitly setting the size of the inner frame, though, so it can't grow or shrink.

Comment: I did remove size parms but the result was the same. Also edited first post in order to add the revised version of the code.

Comment: I dug a little deeper and found out that a canvas itemconfig was needed to make the inside frame size keep pace with the canvas size. Job done. Thks for invaluable help.